# How to add custom loading image in CustomBox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am using CustomBox plugin (http://dixso.github.io/custombox/) for modal dialog. When I click button to open dialog, it loads image (or icon) that is inside library code. It has only property `loader`, but there is no custom image icon attribute.

```
var modal = new Custombox.modal({
    content: {
        target: '#open',
        effect: 'fadein',
    },
    loader: {
        active: true,
        color: '#fff',
        speed: 1000,
    }
});
modal.open();
```

The problem is loading animation lasts less then a second, so I can not catch this container with dev tool to get image/icon source.

Comment: It's a div , by which image do you want to change it ?

Comment: simple css/svg/gif animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by ovveriding the loader css style 
and setting custom background + removing the border (set to 0 ) also remove css animation .

PS: the speed loader seems doesn't work correctly , because whether changing the value or not the image show only for a bit

See below snippet :

```js
var modal = new Custombox.modal({
    content: {
        target: '#open',
    },
    loader : {
      active: true,
      background: '#4d0',
      speed:10000
    }
});
setTimeout(function(){

  modal.open();
},1000)
```

```css
.custombox-loader{
  background:url('https://gifimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/gif-uploader-10.gif') no-repeat;
  background-size:100%;
  border-width:0px !important;
  animation-name:none!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/custombox/4.0.3/custombox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/custombox/4.0.3/custombox.min.js"></script>


<div id="open"></div>
```